# How is Ryan responsible?

Tags: the-boys-2019

In season 2, episode 8 of The Boys Becca is killed at the end of a fight between Stormfront and Ryan.

All the characters treat this as an accident, but an accident that Ryan is definitely responsible for.

How is it possible that Ryan is directly responsible? The only thing Ryan does is blast at the group with heat vision, while Becca appears to die from a rather large gash across the neck.

To make it clear that the show holds Ryan directly responsible for Becca's death, the next scene has Homelander trying to take Ryan away and includes the line

> ...to save the little shit that murdered your wife.

And the in-store trivia items provided by Amazon say

> In the comics Becca was also killed by her own Superhero child...

Comment: I'm actually curious as to why this was warrant a downvote. It looks okay.

Comment: Are you thinking along the lines of maybe Stormfront killed Becca before Ryan attacked, and Ryan is getting blamed for the death when he didn't actually do it?

Comment: @fez that's it exactly.

Comment: "Months later, Becky died when she prematurely gave birth to a super-powered fetus, who apparently ripped itself out of her womb. The fetus tried to kill Billy with its laser-sight, forcing him to beat it to death with a lampstand." Can see why that was modified for the TV version.

Comment: @Michael honestly not sure the gore factor had any influence on the changes for TV. There are more interesting stories to hang off Mother and Child's survival.

Comment: @fez I cant see this being the case when its clearly shown Stormfront to be squeezing her neck slowly, and "She likes to watch the lights go out" when doing so. If anything she would have crushed through her neck and potentially decapitated her rather than leaving a gash.

Comment: I'm more along the lines of the blast ripped Stormfront away from Becca, and the force of her grip being pulled sideways inadvertently tore out a chunk of her neck.

Answer (score 3):

Its implied that he hit her with his heat vision when attacking Stormfront.

This is made clear by her not having a neck wound before he started blasting and him saying "I'm Sorry" over and over.

Comment: The same heat vision that removes Stormfront's limbs, leaves her charred across the rest of her body opens up a clean gash on Becca's neck with no scarring? That just seems unlikely. Ryan's apology doesn't mean he caused it, he's a scared kid whose mum is dying after they had a big falling out. But your interpretation is consistent with all the other characters'  actions.

Comment: @Jontia Its shown before in the series (Season 1, Baby Scene) that heat vision can cut of limbs and cause woulds that still bleed. Its doesn't necessarily instantly cauterize the wound. I imagine its because he just clipped her with it rather than directly focusing on her for a few seconds like he was with Stormfront.

Comment: @Jontia Stormfront had her hands around Becca's throat. The next we see her, she's lying on the ground with both lower legs torn off.  The cut could have been caused by Stormfront's  fingernail as Ryan's laser vision ripped her away.

Answer (score -1):

He's only directly responsible for severely maiming Stormfront. Unfortunately it still didn't save his mother, maybe even caused Stormfront to finish her off instantly, but he's hardly responsible for that. Homelander's comment is just him being an ass and trying to manipulate Billy, but he fails completely. Amazon seems to overstate this because of what happened in comics.

Comment: That doesn't really match up with Homelander's comments or the trivia text. Though it would make sense in isolation. Especially given Ryan's closeted upbringing.

Comment: I checked it up in the show and edited answer.

Comment: And now my answer got a -1 and the one hardly making sense +2, why do I even bother?

Comment: This was a fairly big edit. Mostly reversing the previous version. While you've still got an upvote from me that sort of edit isn't really ideal.